# Uploading images to a site

Tags: php, html

I'm working on allowing userse to upload thumbnails of themselves to my site. The code I have is

```
$allowedExts = array("jpg", "jpeg", "gif", "png");
        $explode = explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
        $extension = end($explode);
        if ((($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/gif") || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpeg") || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/png") || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/pjpeg") ||   ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "images/jpg")) && ($_FILES["file"]["size"] < 50000) && in_array($extension, $allowedExts))
        {
            $sDate = date("m-d-Y");
            $sRandString = randomString(50);
            $sFileName = rename($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], $sDate . $sUsername . $sRandString);   //The name of the file
            $sTargetLink = $_PARAM["ThumbnailDir"] . $sFileName;
        
            if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0)
                echo "There has been an unexpected error, we're working on fixing it as soon as possible. Please try again later.";
            else
            {
                if (file_exists($_PARAM["ThumbnailDir"] . $sFileName))
                {
                    unlink($_PARAM["ThumbnailDir"] . $sFileName);
                    $sFileLocation = $_PARAM["WebsiteAddress"]."images/thumbnails/".$sFileName; //The location of the file
                    move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],$_PARAM["ThumbnailDir"] . $sFileName);
                    echo "The thumbnail has been successfully uploaded.";
                    unlink($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"]);
                }
                else
                {
                    $sFileLocation = $_PARAM["WebsiteAddress"] . "images/thumbnails/" . $sFileName; //The location of the file
                    $move = move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], $sTargetLink);
                    if ($move) echo "The thumbnail has been successfully uploaded.";
                    unlink($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"]);
                }
            }
        }
```

and then the link location would be saved in the database, allowing a retrievable link to the image. However, whenever submitted, the page returns this:

> Warning: move_uploaded_file(C:\xampp\xxxxx\php3D71.tmp): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\xxxxxxx\xxxxx\xxxx.php on line 117
>
> Warning: move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move 'C:\xampp\xxxxx\php3D71.tmp' to 'C:\xampp\xxx\xxx\thumbnails1' in C:\xampp\xxxxxxxxx\xxx\xx\x.php on line 117

I can't figure out what is wrong. The form is enctype="multipart/form-data" Any suggestions? Thank you.

Comment: It's probably the destination path. Make sure the destination directory is already created.

Comment: What do you get when you echo `$_PARAM["ThumbnailDir"] . $sFileName`? Is it a valid destination, and do you have the correct permissions for the `ThumbnailDir`?

Comment: it echos tumbnails1, that's something I forgot to mention. I want it to save it in thumbnails, but it always moves it to thumbnails1, can't figure that out either. $_PARAM["ThumbnailDir"] is  "C:\\xampp\\xxx\\xxx\\thumbnails"; .

Answer (score 1):

**Issue 1 -**
Try changing to-

```
$sFileName = $sDate . $sUsername . $sRandString;
rename($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], $sFileName);   //The name of the file
$sTargetLink = $_PARAM["ThumbnailDir"] . $sFileName;
```

since `rename()` is returning true, this line -

```
$sTargetLink = $_PARAM["ThumbnailDir"] . $sFileName;
```

is becoming

```
$sTargetLink = 'thumbnails' . 1; //  => thumbnails1
```

**Issue 2 -**
Your `move_uploaded_file()` warnings/errors are because it can not find your `thumbnails` folder. Double check your destination path/directory. Make sure that it is absolutely correct.

Another possible issue is that I don't see a `/` between `$_PARAM["ThumbnailDir"]` & `$sFileName` to denote the folder `thumbnails ~ ($_PARAM["ThumbnailDir"])`. It could be as simple as changing to -

```
$sTargetLink = $_PARAM["ThumbnailDir"] .'/'.$sFileName;
```

Comment: Thank you! that worked for changing the directory, but the move_upload_file function still won't work. I hate to ask for answers, but any idea why?

Comment: I have edited my answer with why `move_upload_file()` is erring out. It could be because you are missing `/` between `thumbnails` and the filename.